# How do I get the number of rows using PDO?

Tags: mysql, pdo, rows

I just started to work with PDO, until now I worked with MySQL. I can't figure out how to get the number of rows with it, I have this code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT verified,vkey FROM accounts WHERE verified = 0 AND vkey = :vkey LIMIT 1';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':vkey', $vkey);

if ($stmt->execute(array($sql))->rowCount() == 1) {
    $update = 'UPDATE accounts SET verified = 1 WHERE vkey = :vkey LIMIT 1';
    $stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($update);
    $stmt2->bindParam(':vkey', $vkey);
}
```

Basically, I need to get the number of rows for the if statement:

```
  if ($stmt->execute(array($sql))->rowCount() == 1)
```

Comment: Why are you passing `array($sql)` as an argument to `execute()`?

Comment: I've found that on a similar question in here.

Comment: You must have misread it. The argument to `execute()` is an array of parameter values. You already used `bindParam()` to provide the parameter value, you shouldn't pass anything to `execute()`.

Comment: Why are you selecting specific columns if you only need the row count?

Comment: either if I don't pass anything to execute it still doesn't get the row count

Comment: that's converted from mysqli. I just want to get the rows that have verified = 0 and vkey = :vkey and then in the if statement to get the number of rows that have those values

Answer (score 1):

`rowCount()` is a method of `PDOStatement`. `execute()` doesn't return a statement, it just returns `true` or `false`.

You should call it on `$stmt`.

```
if ($stmt->execute() && $stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
    // do stuff
}
```